# findContours in OpenCV doesn't match bwboundaries in Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm looking for C++ code (doesn't have to be in OpenCV) that gives the exact equivalent results to the Matlab `bwboundaries` command. I see there's `findContours` in OpenCV, but it is not giving the same results as `bwboundaries` is

The code I used for `findContours` is:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("lennabin.bmp");
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours0;
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat tMat;
cv::transpose(mat, tMat);
//findContours(mat, contours0, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
findContours(tMat, contours0, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
//findContours(mat, contours0, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::cout << "\nopenCV findcontours L:"<< contours0.size()<<"\n";
for (int i = 0; i < contours0.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "\ni: "<<i<<" points: "<< contours0[i].size();
    int jsize;
    if (contours0[i].size() >= 5) {
        jsize = 5;
    }
    else {
        jsize = contours0[i].size();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < jsize; j++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n"<<contours0[i][j].x << " " << contours0[i][j].y;
    }
}
```

and the code for `bwboundaries` is:

```
[B,~,~] = bwboundaries(im);
disp(['Length(B): ', num2str(length(B))])
for i=1:3
    disp(['Length(B{i}): ', num2str(length(B{i}))])
    disp(['i: ',num2str(i)])
    boundary=B{i};
    [r,c]=size(boundary);
    if r<5
        jL=r;
    else
        jL=5;
    end
    disp('xy')
    for j=1:jL
        disp([num2str(boundary(j,1)), ...
            ' ',num2str(boundary(j,2))])
    end
end


for i=1:length(B)
    if length(B{i})==17
        disp(['Length(B{i}): ', num2str(length(B{i}))])
        disp(['i: ',num2str(i)])
        boundary=B{i};
        disp('xy')
        for j=1:length(B{i})
            disp([num2str(boundary(j,1)), ...
                ' ',num2str(boundary(j,2))])
        end
    end
end
```

and the outputs I get for C++ is:

```
openCV findcontours L:220

i:0 points 1
188 206
i:1 points:17
218 202
217 203
216 204
215 205
214 206
i:2 points: 4
8 194
9 193
10 194
9 195
```

and Matlab:

```
run_bwboundaries(lennabind);
Length(B): 220
Length(B{i}): 583
i: 1
xy
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
Length(B{i}): 107
i: 2
xy
172 1
172 2
173 3
174 4
175 5
Length(B{i}): 11
i: 3
xy
205 29
206 29
207 29
208 29
209 29

Length(B{i}): 17
i: 211
xy
139 127
139 128
139 129
139 130
140 130
140 131
140 132
141 132
141 133
141 132
141 131
140 131
140 130
140 129
140 128
140 127
139 127
```

The outputs of the x,y coordinates of the contours don't match, even for the contour with length 17

How can I get them to match? Or is there other C++ code that can get the same results as `bwboundaries`?

**EDIT**

I tried to display the contours in OpenCV with:

```
int indx=0;
for(; idx>=0; idx=hierarchy[idx][0])
{
    cv::Scalar color(255,255,0);
    drawContours(mat, contours0, idx, color, cv::FILLED, 8, hierarchy);
}
cv::namedWindow("Components",1);
cv::imshow("Components", mat);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

but I just see the original image without the contours

## EDIT2

I used the following C++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

std::vector<double> matToArr(cv::Mat mat);

void csvwriteMat(std::string str1, std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec);
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matTo2Dvec(const cv::Mat& mat, int rows);
std::string type2str1(int type);
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> bwboundariesOpenCV(cv::Mat mat);

int main() {

    cv::Mat sampleMat = cv::imread("sample.bmp");
    
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> sample = matTo2Dvec(sampleMat, sampleMat.rows);
    std::cout << "\n sample 2d vec \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < sample[0].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << sample[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }

    cv::cvtColor(sampleMat, sampleMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    sampleMat.convertTo(sampleMat, CV_32F);
    cv::Scalar s = 255;
    divide(sampleMat, s, sampleMat);

    std::string ty = type2str1(sampleMat.type());
    printf("Matrix: %s %dx%d \n", ty.c_str(), sampleMat.cols, sampleMat.rows);
    
    sampleMat.convertTo(sampleMat, CV_8U);
    ty = type2str1(sampleMat.type());
    printf("Matrix: %s %dx%d \n", ty.c_str(), sampleMat.cols, sampleMat.rows);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> B = bwboundariesOpenCV(sampleMat);
    for (int k = 1; k <= B.size(); k++) {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> boundary = B[k - 1];
        std::string outputDir1 = "C:/Users/me/output";
        std::string out1 = outputDir1 + "/" + "OpenCV-bwboundaries" + "/" +
            "contour" + "-" + std::to_string(k) + ".csv";
        csvwriteMat(out1, boundary);
    }

    return 0;
}

std::vector<double> matToArr(cv::Mat mat)
{
    cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32F);
    cv::Scalar s = 255;
    divide(mat, s, mat);
    std::vector<double> array;
    if (mat.isContinuous()) {
        array.assign((float*)mat.data, (float*)mat.data + mat.total());
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
            array.insert(array.end(), mat.ptr<float>(i), mat.ptr<float>(i) + mat.cols);
        }
    }
    return array;
}


void csvwriteMat(std::string str1, std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec)
{
    const char *str = str1.c_str();
    std::ofstream out(str);
    for (auto& row : vec) {
        for (auto col : row)
            out << col << ',';
        out << '\n';
    }
    out.close();
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> matTo2Dvec(const cv::Mat& mat, int rows)
{
    std::vector<double> arr = matToArr(mat);
    std::vector < std::vector<double>> vec2D;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        auto first = arr.begin() + (rows * i);
        auto last = arr.begin() + (rows * i) + rows;
        std::vector<double> vec0(first, last);
        vec2D.push_back(vec0);
    }
    return vec2D;
}

std::string type2str1(int type) {
    std::string r;

    uchar depth = type & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK;
    uchar chans = 1 + (type >> CV_CN_SHIFT);

    switch (depth) {
    case CV_8U:  r = "8U"; break;
    case CV_8S:  r = "8S"; break;
    case CV_16U: r = "16U"; break;
    case CV_16S: r = "16S"; break;
    case CV_32S: r = "32S"; break;
    case CV_32F: r = "32F"; break;
    case CV_64F: r = "64F"; break;
    default:     r = "User"; break;
    }

    r += "C";
    r += (chans + '0');

    return r;
}


std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> bwboundariesOpenCV(cv::Mat mat) {
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours0;
    cv::Mat tMat;
    cv::transpose(mat, tMat);
    findContours(tMat, contours0, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> B;

    std::cout << "\nopenCV findcontours L:" << contours0.size() << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < contours0.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>>contourVec;
        for (int j = 0; j < contours0[i].size(); j++) {
            std::vector<double>contourXY;
            contourXY.push_back(contours0[i][j].x);
            contourXY.push_back(contours0[i][j].y);
            contourVec.push_back(contourXY);
        }
        B.push_back(contourVec);
    }
    return B;
}
```

and the following Matlab code to display the contours from OpenCV into Matlab (since when I used `drawContours` in OpenCV in C++, I couldn't see the contours drawn):

```
function plotOpenCVcontours(pth, boundarypth,BW1)

close all;
fig=figure(2);imshow(BW1);hold on;
boundarypath = fullfile(pth, boundarypth);
allboundary = dir(fullfile(boundarypath, '*csv'));

for x = 1:length(allboundary)
    thisBoundary=csvread(fullfile(pth, boundarypth, allboundary(x).name));
    sz=size(thisBoundary);
    for j=1:1:sz(1)
        plot(thisBoundary(j,2), thisBoundary(j,1), '.g','MarkerSize',5);
    end
end
```

I then compared those contours with `bwboundaries` in Matlab:

```
figure(81); imshow(I); hold on; [B,L,N] = bwboundaries(I); 
[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(I);
for k=1:length(B),
    boundary = B{k};
    if k>N %hole boundaries
        plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), '.g','MarkerSize',5);
    else
        plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), '.r','MarkerSize',5);
        
    end
end
```

The sample image is:
[image]

The OpenCV result:

[image]

The Matlab result:

[image]

As shown, the contours don't match

Comment: You get 220 contours in both cases. Likely they are identical but sorted differently, I cannot imagine this is an important difference. Did you try drawing the contours and seeing if the resulting images match?

Comment: Have you looked at the source for bwboundaries? It's pretty instructive about the core algorithmic steps if you're interested in replicating the implementation.

Comment: I looked at the source for `bwboundaries`. When I was debugging it, it would hit `B = bwboundariesmex`, and I couldn't find the code for `bwboundariesmex`

Comment: Yes, I tried drawing with `drawContours`, but no contours showed up. Also, I don't think they're the same because in Matlab, only one contour had 17 points in it, and its xy values don't match the OpenCV contours, as I showed in the output

Comment: it is just me or I don't see any index update in the for loop?

Comment: If you're not able to display the contours, how do you know they're correct? I would concentrate on that before you try to match a potentially incorrect output. Can you post your input image? How do you load the image in MATLAB?

Comment: I used new code and images in `EDIT2`. I still see that the results don't match